# Using variable 'i' outside of its function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Okay, I was playing around javascript.  I wanted to create a webpage with a "change background" button that cycled between different colors.  So I wrote it like this (script tag starts out of view)

```
 var bgcolors = ["pink", "beige", "wheat", "white", "brown"];

        var i = 0;

        function cyclebg(){

            document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgcolors[i];

            i++;

            if (i > (bgcolors.length - 1))
            {
                i = 0;
            }

        }

        //other ideas:
        //-say color next to button
    </script>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button"  style="background-color:red; border-color: red;" OnClick="cyclebg()">Change Background Color</button>
```

That worked just fine.  Then I decided to make an edition, and have the name of the color displayed right next to the button.  So I added...

```
<script>document.write(bgcolors[i]);

    </script>
```

However, "pink" is always written.  It seems like this "document.write" script is only capable of reading what "i" is outside the function.  Why is this?  Aren't all variables global in javaSCRIPT?  How can I get it to read what "i" is inside the function, so it displays the name of the color being used in the background?

Comment: `Aren't all variables global in javaSCRIPT?` answer to this is no, scope is a very real thing in JS.

Comment: Also the document.write runs instantly (and only once) as that line is parsed and the function doesnt run until you click the button.

Comment: `document.write`...the `horror`!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an element to target when the button is clicked would be the easiest way of doing what you are trying to accomplish.

HTML

```
<button type="button"  style="background-color:red; border-color: red;" OnClick="cyclebg()">Change Background Color</button><span id="color-name"></span>
```

JS

```
var bgcolors = ["pink", "beige", "wheat", "white", "brown"];

var i = 0;

function cyclebg(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgcolors[i];
    document.getElementById("color-name").innerHTML = bgcolors[i]
    i++;                        
    if (i > (bgcolors.length - 1))
       {
           i = 0;
       }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rt7t1fws/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over the `bgcolors` and `i` by returning a function for changing the color. Then use a `span` tag for the color name.

```js
var cyclebg = function() {
    var bgcolors = ["pink", "beige", "wheat", "white", "brown"],
        i = 0;
      
    return function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgcolors[i];
        document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = bgcolors[i];
        i++;
        i %= bgcolors.length;
    };
}();
```

```html
<br><br><button type="button" style="background-color:red; border-color: red;" onclick="cyclebg()">Change Background Color</button> <span id="color"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like this "document.write" script is only capable of reading
>   what "i" is outside the function. Why is this?

When document.wite is being executed the value of i is 0. As per your code it appears that you are not writing/executing `document.write(bgcolors[i]);` code each time `cyclebg()` is called.

> Aren't all variables global in javaSCRIPT?

A variable declared outside a function, becomes GLOBAL

> How can I get it to read what "i" is inside the function, so it
>   displays the name of the color being used in the background?

See @Jach M's answer. Write code within your `cyclebg()` function to do it.